# Find the finest building blocks

Tags: code-golf, string

Given a string \$X\$ we will say two strings, \$a\$ and \$b\$, are **building blocks** of \$X\$ if \$X\$ can be made by concatenating some \$n\$ \$a\$s with \$m\$ \$b\$s in any order. For example the string `tomato` has building blocks `to` and `ma`:

```
to ++ ma ++ to
```

We will say that the **fineness** of a set of building blocks is the sum \$n+m\$. That is the number of blocks required to build \$X\$. So in the example `tomato` here are some building blocks with their fineness:

```
to, ma -> 3
tom, ato -> 2
tomato, z -> 1
```

### Task

Given a non-empty string as input output a set of two building blocks with maximal fineness. In the case of a tie you may output any or all of the maximal building blocks.

You may assume the input will contain only the alphabetic ASCII characters.

If there is a correct output where \$a\$ is the empty string, you may output only the \$b\$ value.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the goal is to minimize the size of your source code as measured in bytes.

*However*, I make explicit what is usually implicit: you should consider submissions of differing time complexity as belonging to different categories for scoring. I encourage people to try and golf both efficient and inefficient algorithms to this problem.

### Test cases

The following examples have unambiguous (up to order) solutions:

```
tomato -> to ma  F=3
tomcat -> t omca  F=3
banana -> ba na  F=3
axaaaaaaxa -> a x  F=10
axaaaaaaja -> a xaaaaaaj  F=3
aaxaaaajaaaajaaaaxaa -> a xaaaajaaaajaaaax  F=5
```

The following have ambiguous solutions. I've given a possible valid solution and its fineness to compare to your result. I've used the character `*` in the output to represent cases where that string may be empty or omitted (these two options are non-exhaustive).

```
bobcat -> bob cat  F=2
axaaaajaaaaxa -> axa aaajaaa  F=3
axaaaajaaaajaaaaxa -> axa aaajaaaajaaa  F=3
aaaaaaaaaa -> a *  F=10
x -> x *  F=1
```

Comment: For `aaaaaa` what's allowed as output? `a,aa`, `a,a`, `a,`, `a,z`?

Comment: @l4m2 Since the best way to split that is into all `a`s,  any pair that contains `a` as a building block is correct. So all of those are fine but something like `aa, s` or `x, y` would not be.

Comment: Point is `a,` since allowing empty string is quite bad

Comment: `a,` is fine. I don't really understand the point of your question.

Comment: If empty string is allowed then every string x = x + '' + '' + ''

Comment: @l4m2 Yes this is correct. What is your point?

Comment: then all string have infinite fineness

Comment: @l4m2 No, fineness is "the number of blocks *required* to build \$X\$".

Comment: Can we output the degree of fineness along with the building blocks?

Comment: How is the maximal fineness of `tomato` not `t` + `o` + `m` + `a` + `t` + `o` = 6? Isn't the answer always just `string.length`? I probably missed something in the question. EDIT: ohhhh, I think what I missed is that you're only allowed two distinct blocks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <sup><s>14</s> <s>13</s> <s>10</s></sup> 9 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

-1 byte thanks to [@isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg)

```
e<I#2{M./
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72koLIkY8Fit8DApaUlaboWK1NtPJWNqn319CH8BRBqWbSSbopS7M2kaKWS_NzEknwlHQWlpMQ8IASxEisSwaAChZcF4UG4WXACyIWIJ0IYFSACYmpuolIsxEIA)

```
e<I#2{M./Q
       ./Q  # all partitions of input
     {M     # remove duplicates in each partition
 <I#2       # filter for elements where elem[:2] == elem
e           # last element
```

Comment: With the most recent edit to the challenge, you could omit the `.[2`

Comment: You can save a byte by replacing `f>3lT` with `<I#2`. Also, glad to see people using my language!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES11), 107 bytes, \$O(n^3)\$ <sup>*</sup>

*<sup>* or worse, depending on the time complexity of the regular expression algorithm, which is likely to be implementation-dependent</sup>*

A regex-based solution. Much more convoluted than I would like.

```javascript
f=(s,n=(w=s.length)*w)=>n--?s.match(`^(.+)\\1{${x=n%w}}(.+)(\\1|\\2){${n/w-x|0}}$`)?.slice(1,3)||f(s,n):[s]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZJBTsMwEEXFllNYVZFsaBwKG4Tk9iAE1ElI2oZ0vLCrWGpyEjZdtIeCo7DCIW0hsctYsuT5_3k81rzvUL6m2-1-rbPg4eMtE1SNUNBSKF6kONcLdl0yMcEgmCq-Ap0s6OyF8hsWRePNcGMEXpV13SSozVRRdMdsGsMyMNVtXQ9nbMpVsUxSOh7ds6rKmvvZ45N6bkt-XnwlEpUsUl7IOc3oQEtbRg4YI90IQ6IlWcFlzx8D2uX1x0DQ8YOBnzA9xvqBmHPu3Os-aA7UUvlps8cG_4X-SE4_Mk5A-_uRMbGa_42501RTzgA5aP9QHbRL-dFTuJ_S9xq3k6PXtCNwnL5v)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 107 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

```javascript
f=([c,...a],k,u=o=[],s,b=[...u,s])=>c?f(a,k,u,[s]+c)|f(a,-~k,b,c)||new Set(o):new Set(b).size>2||o[k]?0:o=b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBTgMhEIbvPgXpCVJKjccmtA/hkXAYkDXdbRkjVInZ@Oorq211F@qQbJj9vy8wtPAGwb7uX@LK45MbhkZSZbkQAjTv@EmiVJoHbqTK/048aCa3dtdQGFOugl5a1o/t6rPjhuem9@6dPLpIkW0uW8NE2H@47UPfo@r07n6D0gwWfcCDEwd8pg1dRDxCxAVjZFrrNYlIjnA34w34vKq8AeILHhJ8V5o5mQeSbtFtlT5nhfRjtddPbkf9V/oTFfOgsRDr86AhOavfsS2GGo9LQM7ZP9ZEnVp19Vrlo8zZVE5yYdPwBQ)

Comment: does not work for single character inputs

Comment: [104](https://tio.run/##dYxbDoIwEEX/XUVjCGkjlOh/3QigDAgqkRYtMU2AtePgW8Bp0uTeOWdyuIJOLseycqXapV0mOi3WPudch7yAktKtIx1gYg2vaDD4TumcQ1EIjW2VHGi0oXzBgmBZW7Vp2z5QTE0QrBhW0sXSiljTFIzZtt/bXaKkVqeUn9SeZnReKTyl5oyR3/E8UilSwGzAxyDxTfIxEDniwcB9zMBBHoj5R@eT9HM3kh5W/v4w9vpH@lp1Nw)

Comment: @Mukundan314 I've added a quick and dirty fix for these edge cases.

Comment: What's the complexity of JS's regex parser? Is it better than \$O(n^2)\$?

Comment: Isn't the complexity of the first solution at least \$n^3\$? There's no way the regex is sublinear

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 155 bytes, \$O(n^3)\$

```haskell
(%)=splitAt
l=length
x#w=maximum$((w==[],0),x):[((a,b+1),c)|((a,b),c)<-[x#p|y<-x,(s,p)<-[l y%w],s==y]++[(s:x)#p|l x<2,(s,p)<-map(%w)[1..l w]]]
f x=snd$[]#x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZLRboIwFIazW57iBFTaWIxuWbIYerF32F3TxOrqxBUktEpJ3JN4482yZ9qeZi2oUSGh5_zfd2gTOPyshP6USh2P31uzTF5-D6iPqS5VZl5NoKiSxYdZBTaqaS5slm_zHkI1pYyTMSYWTxlCgsyHE0wWeN_WvkoTZqNy36SJJUiT0gcKmn7Niaa04cMhQ3pqsXMU2PTxLOWiRP0as8lopKDmnAdLsFQX7z3GI9sd8e_hKxdZARTKKisMsAoohbdqK2EwgF3su50vURPDTCqZz4A1BCq5k5WW0HAMe0CWgAt3GNIEjNRmIbTUBBCqXBpjR-OWMcYhAuuOElw0tzcLAFBoNrkwm5AAC9slzEXICTxhcsYLYTrsqW-v-VwU7m753C9hcYOFFe1lO6U1rBcm4ztjfW2cops3deL68nDt3cQV85PPp0nbat2u2CU86L7C-Yf5Bw)

Outputs a list of two strings if the input has length \$\geq 2\$, otherwise a list of a single string.

Can be reduced to [136 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XZLRasIwFIbZbZ_iUKdNMBXdGAxpLvYOuwsBo2SzLqmliW3KfIC9w268GXum7WmWtCq6Fnpy_u87SaH9_F4L8yaVOhy-dvYlffz5QENMTaly-2QjRZUsXu06coOGauFyvdO3qKGUcTIlDs8ZEmQ5npEV3oeVr1nK3KDct1nqCDKkDIGCdthwYiht-XjMkJk77B0FLrs7SVqUaNhgNptMFDSc8_59fm_etcgLoFBWeWGBVUApPFc7CaMR1Eno6rBEbQILqaReAGsJVLKWlZHQcgx7QI6AD2sMWQpWGrsSRhoCqPJh4lnSEcY4DMBxHkVnyZ_MIgAU260WdhsTYHFXYi1iTuAekxNeCdvjQEN7yZei8HfHl6HExRUWTnSX65XOcEGYTf8Zm0vjGF3t1Iub88O3_yYuWJh8OE66TutPxT7hUf8NTv_GHw) if outputting more stuff is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

```
ŒṖLÞQ€ṫÐḟ3Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc7p/kcnhf4qGnNw52rD094uGO@8cOdq/5bP2qYo6Brp/CoYa714XZvFa6Hu7ccbgeqivz/vyQ/NzmxhAtIJZbkcyUl5gEhV2JFIhhUIJhZiVwVAA)

A monadic link taking a string and returning a list of two strings.

### Explanation

```
ŒṖ          | Partition
  LÞ        | Sort by length (number of pieces in the partition)
    Q€      | Ubiquity each
      ṫÐḟ3  | Filter out those length 3 or longer (technically those where taking the tail starting at position 3 is non-empty)
          Ṫ | Tail
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 9 bytes, \$O(2^n)\$

```
ṗSᵛuᶻϩḢḢt
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCLhtZvOuyIsIuG5l1PhtZt14ba7z6nhuKLhuKJ0IiwifSIsIltcInRvbWF0b1wiLCBcImJhbmFuYVwiLCBcImF4YWF4YVwiLCBcImF4YWFhamFcIiwgXCJhYWFhYVwiLCBcInhcIiwgXCJ0b21hdG9tYVwiXSIsIjMuNC4xIl0=)

```
ṗSᵛuᶻϩḢḢt­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ṗ          # ‎⁡all partitions of input
 S         # ‎⁢sort by length
  ᵛu       # ‎⁣uniquify each
    ᶻϩḢḢ   # ‎⁤keep only elements with length less than 3
        t  # ‎⁢⁡last element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 65 bytes, \$ O(n^3) \$

```
L$w`(.+)(?=((.+?)\3*)?$(?<=^(\1|\3)+))
$#4¶$1¶$3
N^`.+¶.+¶.*
1G`¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPyvquGe8N9HpTxBQ09bU8PeVgNI22vGGGtp2qto2NvYxmnEGNbEGGtqa2pyqSibHNqmYgjExlx@cQl62oe2gbEWl6F7wqFt/1W4gERJfm5iST4XkEpOLOFKSswDQq7EikQwqEAws4BMCDsLTgC5XEn5SSCNSFJwTVkoQnDAVQEA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
L$w`(.+)(?=((.+?)\3*)?$(?<=^(\1|\3)+))
$#4¶$1¶$3
```

List the fineness and pair of building blocks all substrings of the input whose suffix is a multiple of a second building block whereby the input string can be constructed using only the two building blocks, unless the suffix is empty, in which case it is not counted (this would otherwise throw off the count by `1`).

```
N^`.+¶.+¶.*
```

Sort in descending order of fineness.

```
1G`¶
```

Keep only the pair of building blocks with the greatest fineness. (Alternatively, the `^` can be removed to sort the building blocks in ascending order in which case a `-` must be prefixed to this line so that the greatest fineness is selected.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 116 bytes, between \$O(n^3)\$ and \$O(2^n)\$

Port of [Xcali's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269516/91267)

```python
lambda x,l="":max((subn(a:=(l:=l+i)+sub(r'^(%s)*(.+?)(\2|\1)*$'%l,"|\\2",x),i,x)[1],a)for i in x)[1]
from re import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZHNTtwwEMfFEb9Bb0PEau1ds-puW7WKFLhx5AUIpc6X1ktiR45XCmJ5Ei5c4J3K03T8wSqXJpE98_uPZ8aTl_f-0W61en1rIIP8bW-bi19_bSu6ohIw8jZLkrQTI6XDvlBUpBlt06xdSrZEQM38N50NbEFXyytG880hX7PF-XzW8uSQ55uEj4xLXG7Xd1ywRhuQIBV4QBqjOzA1yK7Xxi5C7Y-TL1XdQLmtywdaCSs4FK0uHwYOiqXk1NR2bxR0wpZbahJf_mlWPZ8nMAOaHJLVTktFwxnmDnFwaRicZXCjVU1IqAfD40BcR61UtWsK_dVgK6mwilQ9h3rscSZORm5kT9lq6Ftp6RwuLmHOyOm9D7pXGIb7UfXapyCVpd6-3aR3yPXeIm0olkCvN04Pt_VFUY558C4s5meeszCh14-TP1bjALRrA9dOAFxn3wjCUlgPwZmBFkLh62ghQEUoRuGf0Qv4ox1efz3y3SePbjwV5N1xQXcSN-Eu_gcpdBEbQguciXhDJllifdwimba3-3_YNPb4hFYW8Sqjc8foEoGdxM-HYTtO-EnCJDsRZtmBz_o9TPof)

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 135 bytes, between \$O(n^3)\$ and \$O(2^n)\$

Port of [Arnauld's regex answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269511/91267)

```python
lambda x:[n:=len(x),[x],*[[m[1],m[2]]for i in range(n*n)if(m:=re.match(r"^(.+)\1{%d}(.+)(\1|\2){%d}$"%(i/n-i%n,i%n),x))]][-1]
import re
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dVHBbpwwEFWO4dY_mK6KYm9ZGraqFCGRY4_9AZZGBkzXGxgj45WImp77Eb3kkvxT8jUZg3fFpUbY894b-83Y_176B7vX-PTcQAa756NtNjevf1vRlbWAMc0xzVqJbORRPhbROs-7PCmiLt8WRaMNKFAIRuAvyXCNXDWsSzMj407Yas_M6ieLP_Nd8jus_7iI7ZLH3ZY7-GkVMvUFNyrEiH4ejZwXRb5JikB1vTYWjJzLebv4UMsGqr2s7lktrIigbHV1P0SAPA0ujbRHQ1UsXcPBm0AIbPW4ig9aIZu3cbcvAncSh48Z_NAog5Pp8DAErrFWoXS9EY4HWyskI4V9BHLs6aacTLxRPePx0LfKsivY3MIVDy7vpqQ7pDRaz-qknQSFlk1xvk0L4vXREtswsiDUG6fPDU-mJPtD-QT4fDNPbxfXVlPX2nnT3AmA79nXgMhK2IkEF85sKZA-x5YC0JNiFNMYJ4He3NHJ9Zk_nHgP_a5ZPpwngou8Be_yvwWlLn1BFIELid4Gi1O8Py2eWZZ3-H_aMvc85lLWvpXRwdHD-ebeAQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage), \$O(2^n)\$

```
.œé€Ùʒg3‹}θ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9vc2FiaWX//y7Fk8Op4oKsw5nKkmcz4oC5fc64//90b21hdG8) or [verify (almost) all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeV/vaOTD6981LTm8MxTk9KNHzXsrD2347/O/2ilkvzcxJJ8JR0QIzmxBMhISswDQiAjsSIRDCqQOVkgTlJ@EkQtRDQLoQoOgJwKpVgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
.œ         # Get all partitions of the (implicit) input-string
  é        # Sort them by length
   €Ù      # Uniquify the parts of each partition
     ʒ     # Filter the partitions by:
      g    #  Where the length (aka the amount of unique parts)
       3‹  #  Is smaller than 3
     }θ    # After the filter: pop and keep the last one
           # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 88 bytes, worst case \$ O(2^n) \$

```
ＦＬθ⊞υ⟦¹…θ⊕ιω✂θ⊕ι⟧ＦυＦΦ⎇§ι²✂ι¹¦³¦¹⊞ＯＥ§ι³…§ι³⊕λ§ι¹¬⌕§ι³κ⊞υ⟦⊕§ι⁰§ι¹⎇⁼κ§ι¹§ι²κ✂§ι³Ｌκ⟧✂⌈Φυ¬⊟ι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHNT8MgFL/7V3B8L8HEbcedzKLJEqdN9GY8vFC0WAotA@3@emTUGqxygLzP3weiIScs6RhfrWNwJ82bb2BAZFU4NhA4e15xtjsJLXeN7WHgbG@Ek500XtagEDn75OxRKyH/Kb7g9iIvDsjye6u0lw6epDPkTnDt96aWIyjO1jivSUHC3KQ7pc40HnrpyFsHB@rLkQ2W1BaFkonGM8@iYZUT99YnQqZejrapWhhQbio6r/7s5GzWdTME0kdol6C/4nWGmlUvOHz/RDt5WDllPEyNBxpVF7rZyjDpqJIDCrOshLONkWikdN5/rhTGyw/9BQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
ＦＬθ⊞υ⟦¹…θ⊕ιω✂θ⊕ι⟧
```

Get all the prefixes of the input string as a list `[1, prefix, empty string, suffix]` where `1` represents the number of building blocks used so far.

```
Ｆυ
```

Perform a search over the possible building blocks.

```
ＦΦ⎇§ι²✂ι¹¦³¦¹⊞ＯＥ§ι³…§ι³⊕λ§ι¹¬⌕§ι³κ
```

If two building blocks have already been picked for this entry then just search those entries otherwise search both the original building block and all of the prefixes of the string remaining. Keep only those where the string remaining starts with the prefix.

```
⊞υ⟦⊕§ι⁰§ι¹⎇⁼κ§ι¹§ι²κ✂§ι³Ｌκ⟧
```

Create a new entry with `1` more building block and the block removed from the suffix, updating the second building block if it is new.

```
✂⌈Φυ¬⊟ι¹
```

Get the entries where the entire string was successfully built, find the one with the most blocks used and output the blocks.

The performance is \$ O(2^n) \$ because on an input of `n` `a`s the code will try both the building block `a` as the first possible building block and also `a` as the next possible building block for each character, generating two child entries each time. An input of `16` `a`s takes about half a minute on TIO. This can be improved at a cost of `6` bytes so something probably about \$ O(n^3) \$:

```
ＦＬθ⊞υ⟦¹…θ⊕ιω✂θ⊕ι⟧ＦυＦΦ⎇§ι²✂ι¹¦³¦¹⊞ＯΦＥ§ι³…§ι³⊕λ⁻κ§ι¹§ι¹¬⌕§ι³κ⊞υ⟦⊕§ι⁰§ι¹⎇⁼κ§ι¹§ι²κ✂§ι³Ｌκ⟧✂⌈Φυ¬⊟ι¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHBTsMwDL3zFT46UpDYdtwJTSBNolAJbohDlBoaNU3aLIHt60OWUil0yyGR/Wy/5xfZCiet0DF@Wgf4RObLtzgyBnU4tBg4vK847E5S0661A44c9kY66sl4alAxxuGHw6tWkq6AH2x7kwcHBvl9VNqTwzdyRrgT3vu9aeiIisOazWNSkDg36U6ps4yXgZzw1s3dlRjKzg0rFS6AUpBmZ7mVMuGAHYeicpWRi8Sz9YnTNMuhXUILh0qOovLuYiaHefGHMQh9RcW/eJ2pZlsWGv6@qptMrp0yHqfCShxVH/rZrTDtUSdvFMtrJZ5tjGJx4u23/gU) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: As above, but when choosing the second building block, does not allow it to be the same as the first building block (or a multiple, not that that makes much difference, since the pathological case was for the two being equal).

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 16 bytes, \$\mathcal{O}(n2^n)\$

```
g1 lL3<nb<<sJ<pt
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoUALiijsDQxJzMtMzVFIaAoNac0JXVpaUmarsWmNNt0Q4UcH2ObvCQbm2Ivm4ISiMTNsNzEzDzblHwuBYWCIgUVhTQFpZL83MSSfCUkkcTExAogzgJiZOGk_KTkxBI0hWCgBDF9wQIIDQA)

### Explanation

- `pt`: get all partitions
- `sJ`: sort them by length
- `nb`: remove duplicate elements from each partition
- `g1`: get the first one such that ...
- `lL3`: its length is shorter than 3

### Reflection

I've tried many ways to do this. I was working on a fast version, but there were so many serious gaps where I couldn't make it work.

- There should be versions of `pt` and `pST` which output partitions sorted by length. There should also be functions to get partitions of a certain size. This would not only shorten the existing code, but it would make it \$\mathcal{O}(2^n)\$.
- There should be joined versions of `l2q` and `l3q`. While we're at it, there should also be a joined version of `l2`.
- There are a bunch of related things I really would have liked here:

  - There should be a function to take a substring and split along that. (There exists one for elements, but not substrings.)
  - There should be a function to take a substring and split along the substring leaving occurences of it in place. e.g. `f "ma" "tomato" = ["to", "ma", "to"]`.
  - There should be a function to take a string and replace all instances of that string with another string. (There exists one that replaces the *first* instances but no more.)
  - There should be a function to take two elements `a` and `b` and replace all instances of `a` with `b`.
  - There should be a function to take a predicate and an element and replace all elements in a structure satisfying the predicate with the given element.